# MongoDB index has no effect

Tags: mongodb, indexing

MongoDB server version is 3.2.
the collection structure is

```
{
   _id: ...,
   array: [
     {
       my_id:...,
       load:...
     }
   ]
}
```

the array has 100k+ items, I add index `db.collection.createIndex({"array.myId": -1})`(**its my wrong,it should be `array.my_id`***)
with the cmd `db.collection.find({"array.my_id": ...})`. it takes 6-8s no matter how I added the index.

Why is there no reduction in execution time with the above index?

Comment: please share a sample document.

Answer (score 1):

`db.collection.createIndex({"array.myId": -1})` targets property `myId`

whereas

`db.collection.find({"array.my_id": ...})` targets property `my_id`

So you search for a different field than your index is built on